# Subspace $Y$ of metric space with finitely many points is complete.

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Show that if a subspace $Y$ of a metric space consists of finitely many points, then $Y$ is complete.

This is what I have so far, but I don't know where to go from here:

> Suppose the the subspace $Y$ of a metric space consists of finitely many points. Suppose $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. Then given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that if $m, n > N$ then $d(x_m, x_n) <\varepsilon$.

Ideally I would show that every Cauchy sequence converges to an element in the subspace, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that, *because $Y$ is finite*, we have
$$0<\inf_{\substack{x,y\,\in Y\\ x\neq y}}d(x,y).$$
Now, what can you conclude when you take
$$\epsilon<\inf_{\substack{x,y\,\in Y\\ x\neq y}}d(x,y)\quad ?$$

Comment: I was thinking about this earlier, it means that you can create a ball around any point that only contains that point and no other points of $Y$. But, I don't see where to take that. It reminds me of the Discrete Metric space, since we can do that there too.

Comment: Indeed, the subspace topology that $Y$ inherits is the discrete topology. What must be the case about the sequence $(x_n)$, all of whose entries are in $Y$, when the distances between its terms get smaller than the smallest non-zero distance in $Y$?

Comment: It becomes constant, and then it must converge to that value? Hence, it converges to an element in $Y$?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly right!